# Bootstrap Navbar collapse toggle not working when directly copy and pasted from documentation

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am copy and pasting the bootstrap documentation navbar https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/ directly into a react component:

```
export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    Navbar
                </a>
                <button
                    class="navbar-toggler"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a
                                class="nav-link"
                                href="#"
                                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
                            >
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a
                                class="nav-link"
                                href="#"
                                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
                            >
                                Link
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a
                                class="nav-link disabled"
                                href="#"
                                data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
                            >
                                Disabled
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

The Navbar displays correctly when previewed and expands when clicked correctly, but when I click the toggle again it does not collapse. When inspecting the element and clicking I see this change:

```
<div class="collapse **collapsing**" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

but nothing changes on my page. I have bootstrap 5.2 installed locally and am able to use other bootstrap features on my page. Other collapses work fine as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap depends on its JS for some functionality. Have you imported the JS bundle (preferably in your global app file)? If not, please do. If you have, then consider using [ReactStrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) which is optimized for react.

https://reactstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you already have imported all the dependencies. Some components require JavaScript plugins and Popper to work properly.

Read more about this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Also https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#components for more specific components that require those plugins.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the reply. I double checked everything and still nothing. I have both popper and bootstrap scripts at the near bottom of my public index.html. I also have both installed through npm and they're in my package.json. To explain more about the specific problem: I can click my hamburger menu and it will expand. If I click one of the default links included, Home or Link, it will collapse the menu. But when I click the hamburger menu to open it and then click the hamburger menu to close it, it does not collapse.